# Should I write "*a* splitting field" or "*the* splitting field"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field, article-writing

I am studying from Patrick Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*, and in section 3, he makes the following definitions.

> Let $K$ be an extension field of $F$.
>
> 1. If $f(x) \in F[x]$, then $f$ *splits* over $K$ if $f$ factors completely into linear factors in $K[x]$.
> 2. If $f(x) \in F[x]$, then $K$ is a *splitting field* of $f$ over $F$ if $f$ splits over $K$ and $K = F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the roots of $f$.
> 3. If $S$ is a set of polynomials over $F$, then $K$ is a *splitting field* of $S$ over $F$ if each $f \in S$ splits over $K$ and $K = F(X)$, where $X$ is the set of all roots of all $f \in S$.

Often, in mathematics, we take care to use the article **the** only when the object we are talking about is unique in some sense. This sense is made precise by defining isomorphisms, or homeomorphisms, or any such (bijectively) structure-preserving functions between objects.

So, it makes sense to start out by talking only about **a** splitting field, because a priori we do not know any two splitting fields of a collection $S$ of polynomials over $F$ are unique up to isomorphism. After such an isomorphism has been shown to exist, we might choose to switch the article and only refer to **the** splitting field of a collection $S$ of polynomials over $F$.

My problem is that Patrick Morandi freely switches between the two articles when referring to splitting fields, both, before and after proving the Isomorphism Extension Theorem (which proves that splitting fields are unique up to isomorphism). This is a bit jarring for me. I would like to know whether there is any standard regarding which article to use when taling about splitting fields.

(I would love it if the answer is "Yes, use **the** once you've proved the Isomorphism Extension Theorem, otherwise stick to **a**." But, I fear that this question is all about nitpicking.)

Comment: I normally think this in terms of $F$ and $K$ are sitting in some ambient fixed algebraic closed field. The splitting field really depends on $F\to\bar{F}$ embedding where $\bar{F}$ is the algebraic closure as you know all algebraic closures of $F$ are isomorphic. Once $\bar{F}$ is fixed. Then I would have no trouble to identify the splitting field as there is only 1.

Comment: @user45765 I am tempted to add an edit to the question based on your comment. You said "**the** algebraic closure" of $F$, whereas Patrick Morandi refers to it using both articles, **the** as well as **a**, before and after proving that all algebraic closures (of $F$) are isomorphic.

Comment: @user45765 also, based on your comment, if I always think of a fixed algebraic closure $\bar{F}$ of $F$, then it makes sense to refer to **the** splitting field $K$, isn't it? That is what I understand from your comment, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. If you fix an ambient algebraic closure of $F$, then the construction of splitting field is done by adjoining all relevant roots of that algebraic closure. There is no extra freedom once you have fixed algebraic closure. Then you have no trouble to say it is "the" splitting field in that particular algebraic closure. Or I do not know what does one mean splitting field in general. There are lots of identifications here.

Comment: @user45765 Thank you, your comments really helped. Yet, Patrick Morandi says "**the** splitting field" even when he hasn't fixed an ambient algebraic closure, says "**a** splitting field" even when he has fixed an ambient algebraic closure, says "**an** algebriac closure" even when he has fixed an ambient algebraic closure. . . . So, I can only conclude that he isn't following your rule :) but, I think I shall!

Comment: Probably the reason is that the author obviously knows the isomorphism theorem and is accustomed to say “the splitting field”, so a couple of slips in the textbook can't be that surprising. Anyway, you're right: before proving that splitting fields are unique up to an isomorphism fixing the base field, one should use “a”.

Comment: @egreg thank you; and once the isomorphism theorem is proved one should ideally use “the”?

Comment: @Brahadeesh Not necessarily. I'd keep the distinction when clarity requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize a lot of what has been said in the comments (which I tend to agree with), you should use the article "**a**" before you know the theorem (or if you are talking to someone else who doesn't know the theorem or any context where before we assume we know the theorem, $\dots$). After that, it is uaually safe to refer to "**the**" splitting field of a polynomial; this frequently happens on this site. However, if there is a need for a distinction between two splitting fields that are not equal (even though they are isomorphic), then we should keep that distinction. But I think such situations are rare.

(Side remark: This reminds me of how in the representation theory textbook by Fulton and Harris, they will put an "$=$" sign for two algebraic structures even when they are only canonically isomorphic but are not equal. I think that the kind of talk we are using here shows up quite a bit in algebra)